# Can't implement changing of the bar colour in Core Plot Bar Chart

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, bar-chart

I have a simple Bar Chart with 12 bars. For this purposes I use Core Plot. I need to implement the method which colour the bars according to their values from light blue for minimum value to the dark blue for the max one.

Now I coloured all the bars in one colour:

```
self.barPlot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:100.0f / 255.0f green:192.0f / 255.0f blue:245.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

I know the method which can set the colour for every bar:

```
-(CPTFill *)barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

But I can't find a good code for my purposes. Any help?

Comment: So, is the main problem how to map values to colors? Otherwise the second method you mentioned is exactly what you need!

Comment: Yes, how to make the correct gradient from light blue to dark blue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the code of the solved issue. Thanks for you support.

```
    - (CPTFill *) barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CGFloat minValue = [[[[[PlotDataStore sharedInstance] docsCount] valueForKey:@"docs"] valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] floatValue];
    CGFloat maxValue = [[[[[PlotDataStore sharedInstance] docsCount] valueForKey:@"docs"] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"] floatValue];
    CGFloat value = [[[[[PlotDataStore sharedInstance] docsCount] valueForKey:@"docs"] objectAtIndex:index] floatValue];
    CGFloat resultHue = (value * 0.6f / (maxValue - minValue)) + 0.4f;

    return [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:0.561f saturation:resultHue brightness:1.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, does it work?

```
CPTGradient *barGradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:[CPTColor blueColor] endingColor:[CPTColor blackColor]];
self.barPlot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:barGradient];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a color from RGB values as you do already to calculate the fill in your first code example. To map values to colors you can for example set Red to 0, blue to 255 and then vary the green from 0 dark blue to 255 light blue. This is not the best solution, better would be to also change the blue value according to your value. You may want to use the OS X color well and try around a bit using the RGB sliders.